# Understanding pandas.read_csv() float parsing

Tags: python, pandas, floating-accuracy

I am having problems reading probabilities from CSV using `pandas.read_csv`; some of the values are read as floats with `> 1.0`.

Specifically, I am confused about the following behavior:

```
>>> pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO("column\n0.99999999999999998"))["column"][0]
1.0
>>> pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO("column\n0.99999999999999999"))["column"][0]
1.0000000000000002
>>> pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO("column\n1.00000000000000000"))["column"][0]
1.0
>>> pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO("column\n1.00000000000000001"))["column"][0]
1.0
>>> pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO("column\n1.00000000000000008"))["column"][0]
1.0
>>> pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO("column\n1.00000000000000009"))["column"][0]
1.0000000000000002
```

Default float-parsing behavior seems to be non-monotonic, and especially some values starting `0.9...` are converted to floats that are strictly greater than `1.0`, causing problems e.g. when feeding them into `sklearn.metrics`.

The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) states that `read_csv` has a parameter `float_precision` that can be used to select “which converter the C engine should use for floating-point values”, and setting this to `'high'` indeed solves my problem.

However, I would like to understand the default behavior:

1. Where can I find the source code of the default float converter?
2. **Where can I find documentation on the intended behavior of the default float converter** and the other possible choices?
3. Why does a single-figure change in the least significant position skip a value?
4. Why does this behave non-monotonically at all?

*Edit regarding “duplicate question”*: This is not a duplicate. I am aware of the limitations of floating-point math. I was specifically asking about the default parsing mechanism in Pandas, since the builtin `float` does not show this behavior:

```
>>> float("0.99999999999999999")
1.0
```

...and *I could not find documentation.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @pvg, this is not a dupe.  OP has carefully demonstrated non-monotonic behavior, and is asking from some illumination so that they can work with it productively.

Comment: @StephenRauch it's either a dupe or there is a related dupe. Look at the desired precision and the results, these are all smaller than the epsilon of an ieee double. It's not really a sensible place to operate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MaxU already showed the source code for the parser and the relevant tokenizer [`xstrtod`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.1/pandas/_libs/src/parser/tokenizer.c#L1451-L1623) so I'll focus on the "why" part:

The code for `xstrtod` is roughly like this (translated to pure Python):

```
def xstrtod(p):
    number = 0.
    idx = 0
    ndecimals = 0

    while p[idx].isdigit():
        number = number * 10. + int(p[idx])
        idx += 1

    idx += 1

    while idx < len(p) and p[idx].isdigit():
        number = number * 10. + int(p[idx])
        idx += 1
        ndecimals += 1

    return number / 10**ndecimals
```

Which reproduces the "problem" you saw:

```
print(xstrtod('0.99999999999999997'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('0.99999999999999998'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('0.99999999999999999'))  # 1.0000000000000002
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000000'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000001'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000002'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000003'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000004'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000005'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000006'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000007'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000008'))  # 1.0
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000009'))  # 1.0000000000000002
print(xstrtod('1.00000000000000019'))  # 1.0000000000000002
```

The problem seems to be the `9` in the last place which alters the result. So it's floating point accuracy:

```
>>> float('100000000000000008')
1e+17
>>> float('100000000000000009')
1.0000000000000002e+17
```

It's the `9` in the last place that is responsible for the skewed results.

---

If you want high precision you can define your own converters or use python-provided ones, i.e. `decimal.Decimal` if you want arbitary precision:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> import decimal
>>> converter = {0: decimal.Decimal}  # parse column 0 as decimals
>>> import io
>>> def parse(string):
...     return '{:.30f}'.format(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(string), converters=converter)["column"][0])
>>> print(parse("column\n0.99999999999999998"))
>>> print(parse("column\n0.99999999999999999"))
>>> print(parse("column\n1.00000000000000000"))
>>> print(parse("column\n1.00000000000000001"))
>>> print(parse("column\n1.00000000000000008"))
>>> print(parse("column\n1.00000000000000009"))
```

which prints:

```
0.999999999999999980000000000000
0.999999999999999990000000000000
1.000000000000000000000000000000
1.000000000000000010000000000000
1.000000000000000080000000000000
1.000000000000000090000000000000
```

Exactly representing the input!

Comment: I had a look at the `xstrtod` source (thanks @MaxU); the problem is that there is much potential for inaccuracies in the intermediate results, especially `number`, which leads to some strings being parsed in a way that they *don't result in the closest representable float*. (Also, the exponent is not checked for overflow.)

Comment: In my opinion, "high" precision should be used by default; this behavior leads to numeric errors that are higher than I would expect and difficult to detect. *Most of all, this behavior should be documented.* (Or has anybody here found the relevant documentation?)

Comment: No, I haven't found any documentation of that behaviour. Fortunatly in most cases numbers don't have more than 10 decimals and for these numbers it works "good enough". That's optimization for you :/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand how it works - look at the [source code - file "_libs/parsers.pyx" lines: 492-499 for Pandas 0.20.1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx#L492):

```
    self.parser.double_converter_nogil = xstrtod  # <------- default converter 
    self.parser.double_converter_withgil = NULL
    if float_precision == 'high':
        self.parser.double_converter_nogil = precise_xstrtod # <------- 'high' converter
        self.parser.double_converter_withgil = NULL
    elif float_precision == 'round_trip':  # avoid gh-15140
        self.parser.double_converter_nogil = NULL
        self.parser.double_converter_withgil = round_trip
```

[Source code for `xstrtod`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/src/parser/tokenizer.c#L1501)

[Source code for `precise_xstrtod`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/src/parser/tokenizer.c#L1625)