# On the float_precision argument to pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, floating-point, ieee-754

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for the argument in this post's title says:

> **float_precision** : *string, default None*
>
> Specifies which converter the C engine should use for floating-point values. The options are *None* for the ordinary converter, *high* for the high-precision converter, and *round_trip* for the round-trip converter.

I'd like to learn more about the three algorithms mentioned, preferably without having to dig into the source code<sup>1</sup>.

---

**Q:** Do these algorithms have names I can Google for to learn exactly what they do and how they differ?

---

(Also, one side question: what exactly is "the C engine" in this context?  Is that a Pandas-specific thing, or a Python-wide thing?  None of the above?)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Not being familiar with the code base in question, I expect it would take me a long time just to *locate* the relevant source code.  But even assuming I manage to find it, my experience with this sort of algorithm is that their implementations are so highly optimized, and at such a low level, that without some high-level description it is really difficult, at least for me, to follow what's going on.</sup>

Comment: I was just playing around with this using a simple example and as best I can tell everything just gets read in as double precision, regardless of what is specified in the float_precision option.  Without doing more research, I'd tend to assume double (64bits) is fine for 99.99% of all tasks, and otherwise I'd read in as a string and do subsequent processing as needed (64 bits is the essentially the highest float precision supported by numpy/pandas, at least in a normal sense).  But, good question!!!

Comment: I don't have time right now for a proper answer, but reading through https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8002 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/8044 should give you the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked about the actual algorithms - the closest I can find is:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx#L492

This is taken from a related answer, kudos to MaxU ([Understanding pandas.read_csv() float parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247486/understanding-pandas-read-csv-float-parsing))

```
Ordinary: double_converter_nogil = xstrtod
High: double_converter_nogil = precise_xstrtod
Round-Trip: double_converter_withgil = round_trip
```

From here, you're in C-land. You also asked why pandas uses C - critical code paths are written in Cython or C.

Answer (score 2):

These options represent three different approaches to converting characters to a float. The difference is mostly in the precision. While the question did not ask for the code, the code defines the algorithm and is informative.

The `legacy` option uses the following algorithm (which is closely related to this code: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/textreader/blob/master/src/xstrtod.c):

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/573e7eaffd801ee5bd1f7685697b51eef5b8ed85/pandas/_libs/src/parser/tokenizer.c#L1478

The default, `high` option, uses the following:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/573e7eaffd801ee5bd1f7685697b51eef5b8ed85/pandas/_libs/src/parser/tokenizer.c#L1615

The `round_trip` option uses Python's own `PyOS_string_to_double` which by all measures is the most complicated. This approach guarantees compatibility with other places Python interprets strings as floats, but sets exceptions and as such must keep the GIL.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/573e7eaffd801ee5bd1f7685697b51eef5b8ed85/pandas/_libs/src/parser/tokenizer.c#L1828

The core of `PyOS_string_to_double` is the private function `_Py_dg_strtod`, (which is closely based on this http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c):

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/054328f0dd3e9ee5a8a026dfcfa606baf7e9f052/Python/dtoa.c#L1439