# Difference in rounding - float64 vs. float32

Tags: python, pandas

This scenario is a simplification of an ETL scenario involving multiple sets of data pulled from MySQL tables. I have a merged dataframe where one price column is type `float64` and the other is type `object`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'price1': [0.066055],
    'price2': ['0.066055'],
})

>>> df.dtypes
price1    float64
price2     object
dtype: object
```

When these two columns are converted to `float64`, the column `price1` is rounded incorrectly when rounded to 5 digits.

```
float64_df = df[price_cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x))

>>> float64_df.dtypes
price1    float64
price2    float64
dtype: object

>>> float64_df[price_cols].apply(lambda x: x.round(5))
    price1   price2
0  0.06606  0.06605
```

However, when the columns are converted to `float32` using `downcast='float'`, the rounding works as expected.

```
float32_df = df[price_cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='float'))

>>> float32_df.dtypes
price1    float32
price2    float32
dtype: object

>>> float32_df[price_cols].apply(lambda x: x.round(5))
    price1   price2
0  0.06606  0.06606
```

Any ideas why the rounding doesn't work properly when both columns are of type `float64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing the floats with higher precision shows that `pd.to_numeric` converted `'.066055'` to `0.06605499999999998872`.

```py
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:0.20f}'.format):
    print(float64_df)
```

Output:

```
                  price1                 price2
0 0.06605500000000000260 0.06605499999999998872
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is `pd.to_numeric` outputs different values for the two:

```py
pd.to_numeric(0.066055)
pd.to_numeric('0.066055')

# 0.066055
# 0.06605499999999999
```

In the case of `0.066055`, it [simply returns the value](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/afe7f1de9bb03a9a1a5122a6e32458225f8c007a/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py#L134).

In the case of `'0.066055'`, I believe it uses [this function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.1/pandas/_libs/src/parser/tokenizer.c#L1451-L1620) for converting the string to a float.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44248213/1455784) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Getting exact numbers with floats is somewhat impossible and floats are always somewhat unpredictable. My guess is that the object results in a float64 a little bit smaller than the original number e.g. 0.066054999999999999 or something similar, resulting in the unexpected rounding result.

Python has some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) about this.